# Empty tuple instead of break in Swift switch statement?

Tags: swift, switch-statement, case

Usually I'd write `break` if I have nothing to execute in a `switch`-case, but this works, too:

```
switch e {
default:
    ()
}
```

What is the meaning here? Execute empty function?

Comment: I think `()` by itself means `Void`, so basically a placeholder line of code that does nothing

Comment: `()` is a *value* of type `Void`. With `default: 13` you would get a “Integer literal is unused” warning, but not with a Void value.